# Google Maps API layers with Heatmaps.js by Patrick Wied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, heatmap

I want to create 2 layers Google map, but it's still doesn't work.
I want to use API by Patrick Wied (http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/index.html) to create my own Google map layer, because I need "count" parameter, not only GPS. I have more than 3000 rows of data with GPS and in every row is number from 1 to 500 and this API can use my 3rd parameter. I didn't find it in Google API.

I need to turn on/off my 2 layers (there are 3 in example, because I began). 1 layer is with heatmap in Patrick Wied Api and the second is with markups.

Now I have a map, but I can't see heatmap layer. What's wrong in my source pls? I am beginner in JS.

Thx you

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap-gmaps.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var layers=[];
var map;


layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wxxx.kml',
{preserveViewport: true});

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wxxx.kmz',
{preserveViewport: true});

layers[2] = new HeatmapOverlay(map, {"radius":20, "visible":true, "opacity":70}).setDataSet(testData);

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 15);
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
}

var testData={
        max: 500,
        data: [
        {lat:   50.1291628  , lng:  12.231887700000016  , count:  1 },
{lat:   50.1654085  , lng:  12.319327599999951  , count:  1 },
{lat:   50.12093429999999 , lng:  12.527273000000037  , count:  1 },
{lat:   50.31434789999999 , lng:  12.610902799999963  , count:  1 },
{lat:   50.1456522  , lng:  12.643388400000049  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.8905022  , lng:  12.654568400000016  , count:  31  },
{lat:   50.2092029  , lng:  12.826413300000013  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.4355419  , lng:  12.869568200000003  , count:  26  },
{lat:   50.3761103  , lng:  13.110478199999989  , count:  1 },
{lat:   50.08908659999999 , lng:  13.157753100000036  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.4910901  , lng:  13.228301399999964  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.6972678  , lng:  13.259076499999992  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.7370899  , lng:  13.326522000000068  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.4081199  , lng:  13.358040500000016  , count:  1 },
{lat:   49.8986734  , lng:  13.37648450000006 , count:  139 }]};

function toggleLayers(i)
{

  if(layers[i].getMap()==null) {
     layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
     layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers("+i+") [setMap("+layers[i].getMap()+"] returns status: "+layers[i].getStatus()+"<br>";
}


</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
Layer1 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
Layer2 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" onclick="toggleLayers(1);"/>
Layer3 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_03" onclick="toggleLayers(2);"/>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve this issue ?